# Lightweight Java solution for creating views on large data

Tags: java, sql, database, jakarta-ee, hsqldb

I need to create a Java (J2EE) application that allows people to generate "views" on large CSV/TSV tabular data. Views might include things like: pagination through the data, sorting, filtering, pivoting and perhaps charting.

My current thinking is to load the data into temporary tables in a database, use SQL to perform the view tasks and then discard the tables.

Can someone recommend a better approach for this that is also fast? 
My constrains are:

- This is a real-time transaction, so Hadoop/Hive is not an option
- Fast response times are important
- I would like to be able to do this in a stateless way where individual requests describe the view (but not at the cost of performance)
- I would like to not have to hand-code view generation, hence the preference for SQL databases.

Comment: Maybe an in-memory DB, like HSQL?

Comment: is HSQL capable of using CSV/TSV files directly as tables?

Comment: Looks like it is: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html, thanks biziclomp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. I find that HSQL does exactly what I need. Looks like [Text Tables](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html) in HSQL are what I would use to create views the way I need.